# Browser that supports regex for Finding text

Tags: browser, plugins

Are there any browsers or add-ons that will let me use regular expressions to lookup text in a page?

Comment: added "plugins" tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firefox with one of several extensions: [/Find Bar/](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/99836/) or [Findfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5104/) or [XUL/Migemo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5239/)
- Konqueror
- [w3m](http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3m)
- [w3m inside Emacs](http://emacs-w3m.namazu.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Firefox add-on [FindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/99836/)?